# Varying Symbols of sign programmatically

Tags: r, permutation, symbols

I have a vector of numbers:

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3)
```

and I want to programmatically analyze the impact of sign change whose
variants could be:

```
v1[1] + v1[2] + v1[3] 
[1] 6
v1[1] + v1[2] - v1[3] 
[1] 0
v1[1] - v1[2] - v1[3] 
[1] -4
v1[1] - v1[2] + v1[3] 
[1] 2
```

How can I exchange signs ('+', '-') programatically? I'm thinking this is a silly question, but can't think my way out of my box, though my line of analysis points to evaluating changing signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick way to get all possibilities with matrix multiplication:

```
signs = rep(list(c(1, -1)), length(v1))
signs = do.call(expand.grid, args = signs)

signs$sum = as.matrix(signs) %*% v1
signs
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 sum
# 1    1    1    1   6
# 2   -1    1    1   4
# 3    1   -1    1   2
# 4   -1   -1    1   0
# 5    1    1   -1   0
# 6   -1    1   -1  -2
# 7    1   -1   -1  -4
# 8   -1   -1   -1  -6
```

If you don't want all combinations, you could filter down the `signs` data frame to the combos of interest, or build it in a way that only creates the combos you care about.

Comment: Your answer rather points out that I've missed possibilities (permutations) that are likely impactful, ie. v1[1] could as well be -v1[1], and the world changes as the grid expands. The further question, given a daisy chain of expand.grid(v1) sign(+/-) expand.grid(v)2 sign(+-) expand.grid(v3) ... which I suppose there are better ways to solve, but clearly still exploring. Chastened, but foolishly not daunted. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris your comment makes this seem like an XY problem - I have no idea what you're applying this to, but I would consider writing up a question about the methods/goals of your analysis and posting it to Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It is 'Gbemi's method` for deriving determinant. [Paper, nxn, n>3](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342783689_Further_Results_on_Gbemi%27s_Method_The_Extended_Sarrus%27_Rule_to_the_Computations_of_the_Determinant_of_n_n_n_3_Matrices), and got 4x4 running reliably in r, though he uses Matlab. Am working on 5x5. The above explodes to 9 x 1024, but I think there is a reliable cycle that makes his use of Laplace method as a checksum possibly unnecessary. I think this is more of a Math/Basis expansion question, but the import and nuance of the answers would probably elude me.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `gtools::permutations` to get all possible permutations of signs, use `apply` to evaluate the values for each combination.

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3)
sign <- c('+', '-')

all_comb <- gtools::permutations(length(sign), length(v1) - 1, v = symbols, repeats.allowed = TRUE)

do.call(rbind, apply(all_comb, 1, function(x) {
  exp <- do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = gsub(',', ' %s', toString(v1)), as.list(x)))
  data.frame(exp, value = eval(parse(text = exp)))
}))

#        exp value
#1 1 - 2 - 3    -4
#2 1 - 2 + 3     2
#3 1 + 2 - 3     0
#4 1 + 2 + 3     6
```

Comment: With vector length `n` and sign length `n-1`, would this still be applicable at `n > 3` , or does it scale (and I knew this would involve regex in some way...)?

Comment: This is scalable. You don't need to change anything in the answer. Try with `v1 <- 1:5`.

Comment: Ok, I'll be back with `?` about still more intermediate `sign('+', '-') aspects as come up  between v1[1:3] (sign)  v2...But this gets me started.

Comment: And I note your 5 (previously 10), as I'm just evaluating 5 and beyond where it appears I have to approach empirically (hence permutation) to arrive at proper sign order as n increases.